# Android Unknown Command 'crunch'

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-sdk-tools

I just installed Eclipse and Android SDK in Mac OS X.

I imported the project to Eclipse and i get the Unknown command 'crunch' error while running the project.

How should I solve this issue.

Please help me

Comment: I updated my sdk a few minutes ago and I have the same problem.Valid projects are not working any more.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I just update 
"Android SDK Platform-Tool" to 8 Rev and "Android Asset Packaging Tool"
from android sdk manager,

and then it works.

Have a try!

Comment: I just struggled with this for a few hours as well, and this fixed it. Additionally, restarting Eclipse and cleaning your project(s) may be necessary depending on your setup. This update (to version 14) changed a lot of how ADT handles library projects, which may introduce some extra headache for you.

Comment: We dealt with this for five hours today. We had to upgrade to rev 8 and then clean the project. viola.

Comment: The update program is not working for me i get 404 for https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml

Answer (score 33):

1. After updating to ADT r14, go to  Window -> SDK Manager (in Eclipse)
2. Check on 'repository', uncheck "installed"
3. Wait for packages to load, then select all [support packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), accept all and install them
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Run your apps on new ADT r14, without 'crunch' errors

Worked for me :)

Comment: I don't see 'support packages' anywhere in my SDK manager :(. I also have an issue with an unknown flag on my aapt tool.

Answer (score 2):

Updating Android SDK Tools to r14 and Android SDK Platform-tools to r8 also solved this problem for me.

I had to check 'Installed' in the SDK Manager in order for the updates to be listed (even though I had the previous versions already installed). Checking only the New/Updates box meant they wouldn't show up in the list.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Window -> Andriod SDK Manager (in Eclipse)
- Check on 'repository', uncheck "installed"
- Wait for packages to load, then select all support packages, accept
  all and install them
- Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
To fix it :
- Uninstall the current sdk tools (Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools) in the Android SDK Manager
- Reinstall them at their last version (r14).

Comment: Installed at r15 only getting 404 errors for the update lists https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml and https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this kind of problem also, when updating SDK,

The solution was to re-enter the SDK folder path to the Eclipse.

(For some reason, the new SDK was instaslltion was in a diffrent folder from the original one)

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was a combination of what [Androgeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507905/androgeek)  and  [tinyau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002883/timyau) said.

Summing up. I needed to update both my Android SDK Tool and Support Tools and restart eclipse.