# Google APIs throw no-crunch error for android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, maps, aapt

I just installed android 2.1 SDK in eclipse and created a project targeted for Google API:7. Eclipse shows an error on the project icon, and the debug window shows this error

`ERROR: Unknown command 'crunch'`
`Android Asset Packaging Tool`

After quite a lot of googling, I still have no idea how to fix this error. I have already tried cleaning up the project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Unknown Command 'crunch'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem has a generic cause ==> Partial ADT Update

Check your repositories again and then this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch/7831692#7831692)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too when I updated Eclipse from Helios to Indigo (on Windows XP)

Solution was to open Android SDK Manager and install all the default selected updates, notably I was on

- Android SDK Tools rev 13
- Android SDK Platform Tools rev 7

These updated to

- Android SDK Tools rev 14
- Android SDK Platform Tools rev 8

My project which targets 2.2 compiles and runs in debug now without any problems (NB I have all the SDKs installed including 4.0 but you can still target earlier SDKs)