# Android programming "no crunch" error

Tags: android, eclipse

i've just installed eclipse and tried to run my first app, unfortunately the error below always 
popped out:

Unknown option '--no-crunch' Android Asset Packaging Tool

I've done the following just like what people adviced but it DIDN'T HELP,

-After updating to ADT r14, go to Window -> SDK Manager (in Eclipse)

-Check on 'repository', uncheck "installed"

-Wait for packages to load, then select all support packages, accept all and install them

-Restart Eclipse

-Run your apps on new ADT r14, without 'crunch' errors

As a result, i keep getting prompt box asking me to momentarily keep deactivating my anti virus. because there might be a program that accessing the directory.

Can anyone please help & provide me the solution??
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had good luck updating the Android SDK tools to revision 15 and Android SDK Platform tools to revision 9.  But this was a stab in the dark that worked.  What I am trying to say is I don't understand the reasons for this to work.  This solution is easy to try.  If it works for you then vote for this answer.

There is a similar question on Stack Overflow at [Google APIs throw no-crunch error for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826266/google-apis-throw-no-crunch-error-for-android)

Other notes:
Running on Windows 7 and Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149.  Compiling for Android 2.2.

Also I updated my Java JDK yesterday to version 1.6.0_25, which may not be relevant but I can't think of another reason for this error to start today.

Android "no crunch" Eclipse aapt "Unknown option '--no-crunch'"

Answer (score 0):

Well, this problem is mainly caused when you have ADT Plugin updated but not repositry in SDK Manager. In Eclipse, Instead of updating sdk manager from Windows -> Android SDK Manager -> Settings... It might not update and normally displays error: Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml. To avoid this, try this solution, hope it surely works:

- Go to folder Android SDK where your sdk is placed(in my case"D:/Android SDK/android-sdk-Windows").
- From this folder double click "SDK Manager.exe".
- When Android SDK and AVD Manager window opened then click Settings.
- In Proxy Settings, it will ask for a HTTP Proxy Server and HTTP Proxy Port.
- Enter the IP address and the port number being asked.
- In Misc Tab check "Force https://... "
- Turn off your firewall and temporarily disable your antivirus.