# ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch' - AAPT error

Tags: android, aapt

I have downloaded latest revision (r14) yesterday. but getting this error while running any application

```
ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
```

Please help...

Comment: Android Asset Packaging Tool  has not been updated somehow. Did you miss it?

Comment: Yes, missed it, support packages, solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch/7831692#7831692

Comment: I'm Goan too :) Drop by the [Android chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) sometime.

Comment: Follow this [topic][1] you can fix your probelm


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch

Comment: If it's solved, please add the solution and mark it as the selected answer so the question is closed :)

Answer (score 7):

I have recently faced this issue.

But it is now **solved**.

After updating to ADT r14, go to `Window -> SDK Manager (in Eclipse)`

1. Check on 'repository', uncheck "installed"
2. Wait for packages to load, then select all support packages, accept all and install them
3. Restart Eclipse

Now you can run your apps on new ADT r14, without 'crunch' errors.

Comment: I think it happened to me after updating the android eclipse plugin but not updating the SDK. Thus, updating the SDK did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think the --no-crunch was dropped from platform-toosl revision 7.
aapt (part of platform-tools) revision 8 is needed to use the latest ADT.