# Eclipse and android ADT error on new installation

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have installed new eclipse and ADT, i have JDK 1.6 installed in the my machine, when i run the android project get this following error.
sample is my project name.

```
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] ERROR: Unknown command 'crunch'
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] Android Asset Packaging Tool
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] Usage:
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]  aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [--max-res-version VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [-I base-package [-I base-package ...]] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G class-list-file] [-P public-definitions-file] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [-S resource-sources [-S resource-sources ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J R-file-dir] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [--product product1,product2,...] \
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]         [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...]
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    Package the android resources.  It will read assets and resources that are
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    supplied with the -M -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    options control which files are output.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]  aapt r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    Delete specified files from Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]  aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]  aapt v[ersion]
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    Print program version.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]  Modifiers:
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    -a  print Android-specific data (resources, manifest) when listing
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    -P  specify where to output public resource definitions
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        compress any files at all.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --debug-mode
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --min-sdk-version
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest.  If the version is 7 or
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        higher, the default encoding for resources will be in UTF-8.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --target-sdk-version
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to manifest.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --max-res-version
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        ignores versioned resource directories above the given value.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --values
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        when used with "dump resources" also includes resource values.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --version-code
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        inserts android:versionCode in to manifest.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --version-name
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        inserts android:versionName in to manifest.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --custom-package
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        generates R.java into a different package.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --auto-add-overlay
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        Automatically add resources that are only in overlays.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --rename-manifest-package
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        does not need to change.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --rename-instrumentation-target-package
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        Rewrite the manifest so that all of its instrumentation
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        components target the given package.  Useful when used in
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        conjunction with --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        a package that has been renamed.
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --product
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        Specifies which variant to choose for strings that have
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        product variants
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]    --utf16
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2011-12-21 00:38:58 - sample]        level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] ERROR: Unknown command 'crunch'
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] Android Asset Packaging Tool
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] Usage:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--max-res-version VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-I base-package [-I base-package ...]] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G class-list-file] [-P public-definitions-file] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-S resource-sources [-S resource-sources ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J R-file-dir] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--product product1,product2,...] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Package the android resources.  It will read assets and resources that are
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    supplied with the -M -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    options control which files are output.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Delete specified files from Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt v[ersion]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Print program version.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  Modifiers:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -a  print Android-specific data (resources, manifest) when listing
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -c  specify which configurations to include.  The default is all
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        configurations.  The value of the parameter should be a comma
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        separated list of configuration values.  Locales should be specified
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        as either a language or language-region pair.  Some examples:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             en
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             port,en
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             port,land,en_US
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        If you put the special locale, zz_ZZ on the list, it will perform
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        pseudolocalization on the default locale, modifying all of the
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        strings so you can look for strings that missed the
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        internationalization process.  For example:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             port,land,zz_ZZ
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -d  one or more device assets to include, separated by commas
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -f  force overwrite of existing files
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -g  specify a pixel tolerance to force images to grayscale, default 0
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -j  specify a jar or zip file containing classes to include
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -k  junk path of file(s) added
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -m  make package directories under location specified by -J
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -u  update existing packages (add new, replace older, remove deleted files)
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -v  verbose output
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -x  create extending (non-application) resource IDs
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -z  require localization of resource attributes marked with
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        localization="suggested"
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -A  additional directory in which to find raw asset files
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -G  A file to output proguard options into.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -F  specify the apk file to output
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -I  add an existing package to base include set
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -J  specify where to output R.java resource constant definitions
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -M  specify full path to AndroidManifest.xml to include in zip
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -P  specify where to output public resource definitions
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        compress any files at all.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --debug-mode
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --min-sdk-version
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest.  If the version is 7 or
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        higher, the default encoding for resources will be in UTF-8.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --target-sdk-version
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to manifest.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --max-res-version
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        ignores versioned resource directories above the given value.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --values
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        when used with "dump resources" also includes resource values.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --version-code
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:versionCode in to manifest.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --version-name
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:versionName in to manifest.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --custom-package
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        generates R.java into a different package.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --auto-add-overlay
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        Automatically add resources that are only in overlays.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --rename-manifest-package
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        does not need to change.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --rename-instrumentation-target-package
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        Rewrite the manifest so that all of its instrumentation
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        components target the given package.  Useful when used in
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        conjunction with --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        a package that has been renamed.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --product
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        Specifies which variant to choose for strings that have
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        product variants
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --utf16
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] Android Asset Packaging Tool
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] Usage:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--max-res-version VAL] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-I base-package [-I base-package ...]] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G class-list-file] [-P public-definitions-file] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [-S resource-sources [-S resource-sources ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J R-file-dir] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [--product product1,product2,...] \
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]         [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Package the android resources.  It will read assets and resources that are
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    supplied with the -M -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    options control which files are output.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Delete specified files from Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  aapt v[ersion]
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    Print program version.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample] 
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]  Modifiers:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -a  print Android-specific data (resources, manifest) when listing
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -c  specify which configurations to include.  The default is all
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        configurations.  The value of the parameter should be a comma
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        separated list of configuration values.  Locales should be specified
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        as either a language or language-region pair.  Some examples:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             en
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             port,en
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             port,land,en_US
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        If you put the special locale, zz_ZZ on the list, it will perform
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        pseudolocalization on the default locale, modifying all of the
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        strings so you can look for strings that missed the
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        internationalization process.  For example:
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]             port,land,zz_ZZ
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -d  one or more device assets to include, separated by commas
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -f  force overwrite of existing files
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -g  specify a pixel tolerance to force images to grayscale, default 0
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -j  specify a jar or zip file containing classes to include
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -k  junk path of file(s) added
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -m  make package directories under location specified by -J
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -u  update existing packages (add new, replace older, remove deleted files)
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -v  verbose output
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -x  create extending (non-application) resource IDs
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -z  require localization of resource attributes marked with
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        localization="suggested"
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -A  additional directory in which to find raw asset files
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -G  A file to output proguard options into.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -F  specify the apk file to output
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -I  add an existing package to base include set
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -J  specify where to output R.java resource constant definitions
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -M  specify full path to AndroidManifest.xml to include in zip
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -P  specify where to output public resource definitions
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        compress any files at all.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --debug-mode
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --min-sdk-version
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest.  If the version is 7 or
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        higher, the default encoding for resources will be in UTF-8.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --target-sdk-version
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to manifest.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --max-res-version
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        ignores versioned resource directories above the given value.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]    --values
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        when used with "dump resources" also includes resource values.
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2011-12-21 00:42:44 - sample]        level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
```

I can not find this error before, so please answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

After updating to ADT r14, go to `Window -> SDK Manager (in Eclipse)`

1. Check on 'repository', uncheck "installed"
2. Wait for packages to load, then select all support packages, accept all and install them
3. Restart Eclipse

Now you can run your apps on new ADT r14, without 'crunch' errors

This solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831253/error-unknown-option-no-crunch-aapt-error)

Comment: still have this problem when upgrade ADT to version 16. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe it's very radical, but try to reinstall Android SDK and ADT?

Comment: you're right. After download and reinstall Android SDK&ADT, it works now.