# Eclipse running Android aapt error

Tags: android

I recently updated my Android SDK r14 and now I get the following error when trying to run my application on emulator.

```
ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
```

I am using Eclipse on Fedora 14 x86_64

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Unknown Command 'crunch'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch)