# Eclipse can't compile a default 'Hello World' Android app

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Unknown Command 'crunch'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch)

I have created a very basic/default 'Hello World' Android app with Eclipse, I just auto-generated it (with ADT plugin of course) without manually adding any single line of code. But strangely the code won't compile. This is the problem I get:

```
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/anas/workspace    /HelloWorld/bin/resources.ap_ does not exist HelloWorld      Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

I get this error in the console:

```
[2011-10-25 14:05:40 - HelloWorld] ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
[2011-10-25 14:05:40 - HelloWorld] Android Asset Packaging Tool
```

What is the cause of this annoying problem?

Comment: how long did you install tha packages ?? try to go on eclipse>help>check for updates  new android 4.0 have new things so :S

Answer (score 0):

Please check following things

1. AVD is properly created
2. SDK path in the Eclipse preference
3. Are you using proper SDK

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem we've seen here before.
Try reading the answers given to this question: [Android Unknown Command 'crunch'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch/7831692#7831692)