# Android - ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'

Tags: android, debugging, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Unknown Command 'crunch'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch)

I have been using eclipse just fine but as soon as I updated it just now, I can't compile my app anymore. I keep getting the following error. Any ideas on how I can fix it? Thanks

```
ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] Android Asset Packaging Tool
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] Usage:
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]  aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [--max-res-version VAL] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [-I base-package [-I base-package ...]] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G class-list-file] [-P public-definitions-file] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [-S resource-sources [-S resource-sources ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J R-file-dir] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [--product product1,product2,...] \
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]         [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...]
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    Package the android resources.  It will read assets and resources that are
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    supplied with the -M -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    options control which files are output.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]  aapt r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    Delete specified files from Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]  aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]  aapt v[ersion]
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    Print program version.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1] 
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]  Modifiers:
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -a  print Android-specific data (resources, manifest) when listing
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -c  specify which configurations to include.  The default is all
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        configurations.  The value of the parameter should be a comma
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        separated list of configuration values.  Locales should be specified
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        as either a language or language-region pair.  Some examples:
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]             en
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]             port,en
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]             port,land,en_US
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        If you put the special locale, zz_ZZ on the list, it will perform
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        pseudolocalization on the default locale, modifying all of the
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        strings so you can look for strings that missed the
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        internationalization process.  For example:
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]             port,land,zz_ZZ
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -d  one or more device assets to include, separated by commas
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -f  force overwrite of existing files
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -g  specify a pixel tolerance to force images to grayscale, default 0
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -j  specify a jar or zip file containing classes to include
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -k  junk path of file(s) added
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -m  make package directories under location specified by -J
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -u  update existing packages (add new, replace older, remove deleted files)
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -v  verbose output
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -x  create extending (non-application) resource IDs
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -z  require localization of resource attributes marked with
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        localization="suggested"
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -A  additional directory in which to find raw asset files
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -G  A file to output proguard options into.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -F  specify the apk file to output
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -I  add an existing package to base include set
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -J  specify where to output R.java resource constant definitions
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -M  specify full path to AndroidManifest.xml to include in zip
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -P  specify where to output public resource definitions
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        compress any files at all.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --debug-mode
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --min-sdk-version
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest.  If the version is 7 or
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        higher, the default encoding for resources will be in UTF-8.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --target-sdk-version
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to manifest.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --max-res-version
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        ignores versioned resource directories above the given value.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --values
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        when used with "dump resources" also includes resource values.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --version-code
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        inserts android:versionCode in to manifest.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --version-name
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        inserts android:versionName in to manifest.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --custom-package
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        generates R.java into a different package.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --auto-add-overlay
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        Automatically add resources that are only in overlays.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --rename-manifest-package
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        does not need to change.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --rename-instrumentation-target-package
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        Rewrite the manifest so that all of its instrumentation
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        components target the given package.  Useful when used in
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        conjunction with --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        a package that has been renamed.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --product
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        Specifies which variant to choose for strings that have
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        product variants
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --utf16
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]    --non-constant-id
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        Make the resources ID non constant. This is required to make an R java class
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        that does not contain the final value but is used to make reusable compiled
[2011-10-30 18:42:14 - LiveFeedr.03-1]        libraries that need to access resources.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you updated the SDK options, but have not updated the ADT.  In eclipse go to Help->Check for Updates and install the newest version of ADT, currently r15

Answer (score 4):

actually, the problem is you updated ADT but SDK, use android SDK manager and update the platform tools and tools, then try again. good luck!