# Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: xxx\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk, android-manifest

Yeaterday I installed some older versions of `google api`'s,after that everything is going wrong.Each project I create it shows "Project contains error fix them". It's showing following errors :

Error generating final archive: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xxx\maps\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist    maps        Unknown Android Packaging Problem
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   maps    Unknown Android Packaging Problem`

I have used `Project->clean` . Deleting `gen` folder again starting but no help. What should I do now ?

Comment: Having same issue here... All projects give same ap_ error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try going to **Window**->**Android SDK manager** and update **Tools** and **Android 4.0**. This solved my issues.

If that doesnt work, try updating everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the Android SDK Tools to revision 8. That worked for me.