# aapt.exe is throwing unhandled exception while building *.apk file for Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, windows, upgrade, apk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i just upgraded my system to Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0) and now everytime I attempt to run my application in the debugger, I get a crash in `aapt.exe`.

If I just build, it builds fine, but when I go to run it in the debugger, `aapt.exe` crashes (which pops up a dialog and asks me if I want to send data to Microsoft) and my project icon in `Project_Explorer` shows that it has error(s).

Answer (score 5):

There is a known issue in AAPT for r15, try to change the build output to normal
http://tools.android.com/knownissues
AAPT crashes on Windows in some cases when the build output is set to verbose.

The workaround is to set

`Eclipse > Preferences > Android > Build > Build Output`

to less than Verbose, e.g. Normal.We have a fix, which will be available in tools 16. [[Issue 20395](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20395)]

Answer (score 2):

In my case this solution doesn't work (Build Output), so I had to think. The problem was with .9.png files (bitmaps with my spinner). I deleted it and aapt.exe works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue with ADT 16.0.1 (released: December 2011). Error occurred when executing `C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe crunch -v -S C:\Do...` and Windows shows an exception thrown from `aapt.exe`.

Then a 0-byte `<myproject>.apk` has been created. And Eclipse shows error `...resources.ap_ file not found...`.

BTW, i am using up-to-date (as of today) Eclipse, android-sdk and ADT.

But my problem was solved just by changing `build output` to `normal` as described in the above solution.

I am also suggesting to change the question title.