# Error for install .apk file on my real device ( htc wildfire s) and emulator run without my application

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in Android programming after compile my project in eclipse without error I see error for install .apk file and emulator run without my application.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you're doing. Could you describe a bit more?
As in, what kind of error does it give you, is USB debugging enabled on your phone? You should take a look at some of these base things.

EDIT:

If you want to install your application to your phone (seperately from Eclipse and debugging), you have to generate a signed APK file. To do this, you right-click your project in Eclipse, open the Android Tools submenu and click Export Signed Application Package. You will be asked for a keystore, make one if you don't have one. You use your keystore credentials to sign the application this way and this will make it installable on a real device.

Comment: Okay, so what kind of errors are you having? I assume you're trying to run as 'Android Application' right? Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: i think my problem is when eclipse do install apk file to device. i try emulate is run good and i can install apk from other developers on it. but my compiled application can't run on android , i see other website article about signe for nadroid apk files. can you help me for do it ?

Comment: i see new error after use export signed , failed export application.

Comment: this is my error in eclips. Description Resource Path Location Type
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dev\workspace2\HelloAndroid\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist HelloAndroid  Unknown Android Packaging Problem
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. HelloAndroid  Unknown Android Packaging Problem
No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document. AndroidManifest.xml ‪/HelloAndroid‬ line 1 XML Problem

Comment: @AbbasS you should check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437023/resources-ap-does-not-exist-when-compile-my-android-project there are a few pointers there

Comment: i have error , oh my god my god . i check all ways but no resolve . please support me remotly by teamweaver . i head to be boomb

Comment: Try and clean your project (Project > Clean) and re-build. Otherwise you should check your Android SDK setup. I'm not too sure what the problem could be anymore and I don't have time for things like TeamViewer sessions.